# Run and break an infinite loop using two threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, infinite-loop

I am trying to run a loop until the user chooses to break out of it. Whether the user wants to run the function all night or for just a few seconds the loop should repeat until the user decides to stop it.

In researching solutions I came across using two threads to achieve this. The first thread would run the infinite loop while the second thread waited for user input. Upon receiving that input the second thread would terminate the first and then return.

- How do I use the second thread to terminate the first?

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void timeCount()
{
    time_t rawTime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    do
    {
        Sleep(500);
        system("cls");
        time(&rawTime);
        cout << "Seconds passed this epoch:" << rawTime << endl << endl;
        timeinfo = localtime(&rawTime);
        cout << "The local time is:" << asctime(timeinfo) << endl;
        timeinfo = gmtime(&rawTime);
        cout << "The UTC time is :" << asctime(timeinfo) << endl;
    } while (1 != 0);

};

void getStop()
{
    system("pause");
};

void timeSince()
{
    thread counter(timeCount);
    thread stopper(getStop);
    counter.detach();
    stopper.join();

    counter.~thread();
};
```

Comment: I actually just realized a solution that I'm kicking myself for not realizing sooner. I added an `int repeat = 1;` and had `getStop()` set `repeat = 0;` after `system("pause");` which worked flawlessly. The `do-while` loop checks `repeat` and exits accordingly but I feel this solution is dirty and probably goes against convention.
Any suggestions on how to do this correctly?

Comment: In principle, what you suggest will work.  In practice, however, the compiler can and will optimize away the check of the variable, because there is no place it is changed (in the thread).  For a cheap hack, you can declare the variable `volatile`; better would be a `std::atomic<bool>` which will work exactly as you want it to.

Comment: I just want to add a comment about your call to thread's destructor. Unless you are using placement new and are handling raw, uninitialized memory yourself, you should **NEVER** call a destructor explicitly. A destructor is automatically called when the variable goes out of scope, and calling it explicitly like you do above may cause your code to crash in certain contexts.

Comment: @Stian That destructor was actually not supposed to still be there. It was left over from my attempts to find a solution earlier. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6):

I usually use an `atomic<int>` or `atomic<bool>` to do it.

---

**Thread function**

```
void run( atomic<bool> & quit ) {
   while (!quit) {
      // Do some work.
   }
}
```

---

**Mainthread:**

```
int main() {
   // Just to show you can do this with more than 1 extra thread.
   unsigned int nThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); 

   std::atomic<bool> loopFlags[nThreads];
   std::thread       threads[nThreads];

   // Start threads
   for ( int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
       loopFlags[i] = false;
       threads[i]   = std::thread(run, std::ref(loopFlags[i]));
   }

   usleep(10000); // Sleep for a while or do something else.

   // Shutdown other threads
   for ( auto & flag : loopFlags ) {
       flag = true;
   }

   // Wait for threads to actually finish.
   for ( auto& thread : threads ) {
       thread.join();
   }
   // Resume what you were doing.
}
```