# What is the best way to kill a running thread after x secconds?

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault

I am working on a c++ project that loads in shared objects and runs a method on them in separate threads. It is a requirement of the system to close down all of these threads after x seconds if they haven’t already terminated. I am able to keep track of which threads have closed but what is the best way to kill one that has not yet finished?

Side Note- Pthread_cancel is causing segmentation faults.

Comment: Is it okay for the threads themselves to arm an alarm which kills them?  Or does an external thread/process have to do it?

Comment: Do you have sample code such as where this segmentation fault is occurring?

Comment: Either one can do it. I am trying to do an alarm right now. I know the alarm is getting triggered but then when I call pthread_exit(NULL). Nothing is happening.

Comment: What platform? Windows? Mac? Unix?

Comment: Unix systems. mainly x_86 and armv7 running monivista

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be done. You *cannot* cancel a thread without its cooperation without risking destroying the process context.

Threads don't provide that kind of isolation. They just don't. If a thread fails, the process fails. You need to contain untrusted or unreliable code in its own process, virtual machine, or the like. Threads are completely permeable.

One of the most common things a thread does is this:

1. Acquire a lock.
2. Break some invariants (protected by the lock).
3. Restore those invariants.
4. Release the lock.

Now imagine if the thread has completed step 2 but not step 3. You can't release the lock (because that would cause the next thread to acquire the lock to encounter the broken invariants) and you can't leave the lock held (because that would cause the next thread to attempt to acquire the lock to wait forever). So the process context would be destroyed at that point.

You need the thread's cooperation to make it restore the invariants.

Comment: in c++ WaitForSingleObject wont that do the trick? just curious.

Comment: @Maddy That doesn't cancel anything, it just waits.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this

`HANDLE myThread = CreateThread(0, 0, stuff to do, NULL, 0, 0);
WaitForSingleObject(myThread , 4000);`

Comment: I know that’s not true though. Pthread documentation has at least two options for killing a thread. Pthread_cancel or pthread_exit(). My question is: is either one better or is there a better option?

Comment: @Maddy, That waits for four seconds and then continues. The other thread is unaffected.

Comment: @nbroeking, *without risking destroying the process context*

Comment: What do you mean destroying the process context?

Comment: `pthread_kill` just sends a signal to the thread.  If the thread ignores it, nothing happens.  If you send an unignorable KILL signal it kills the entire process.  `pthread_exit` can only be called by the thread exiting (it exits the current thread).

Comment: @nbroeking, The answer elaborates.

Comment: @nbroeking By "destroying the process context", we mean making it impossible for the process to continue without risking unpredictable and unreliable operation. (See updates.)

Comment: I went with using thread_cancel and it seems to work fine. It only gets called in an extreme case but it gets the job done.

Comment: @nbroeking If you're happy with code that "seems to work fine", then great. If you insist that code be known to be reliable, then you still have a problem. Does your code have to be reliable? Does it have to withstand independent review? (It's possible to use `thread_cancel` in a reliable way, but it requires the cancelling thread's cooperation.)

Comment: I would like to make it reliable. Unfortunatly the only time thread_cancel ever gets called is when a thread is not cooperating.

Comment: And I appriciate you helping me through this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something along the lines suggested here:

[Run and break an infinite loop using two threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768814/run-and-break-an-infinite-loop-using-two-threads/24769090#24769090)

In short, set up an exit-condition that your threads are required to check every so often. If it is set, they should return. If all threads should die together, you only need one atomic.

Comment: The threads are loaded by a shared object and so the application doesnt have the ability to enforce this.