# How do I use while true in threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Can anyone point me at the thing I try to do in this code, because `SecondLoop` thread is unreachable at all? It becomes reachable only if I remove `while(true)` loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void Loop() {
    while(true) {
        (do something)
    }
}

void SecondLoop() {
    while(true) {
        (do something)
    }
}

int main() {
    thread t1(Loop);
    t1.join();

    thread t2(SecondLoop);
    t2.join(); // THIS THREAD IS UNREACHABLE AT ALL!

    return false;
}
```

The reason why I use multithreading is because I need to get two loops running at the same time.

Comment: What do you mean by unreachable? `t1.join()` in `main()` waits until `t1`'s job is done (and since you use infinite loop, it will never be done, unless you have `break;` somewhere in there).

Comment: Your first created thread runs on a never ending loop, so your are blocked in `t1.join()`. Or something is missing in your skeleton... Do you break the loops?

Comment: Remember that calling [`join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) will *block* until the thread you're joining has exited.

Comment: Nope, I didn't. I guess that's the problem. How should I use `break;` in the loops?

Comment: Joachim Pileborg, how should I create thread then?

Comment: Note that starting a thread and then directly waiting for it to finish isn't really very useful, as it won't be doing any work in parallel. Instead start *both* threads, potentially do some work in the main thread, and finally you wait for the threads to finish.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) blocks the current thread to wait for another thread to finish. Since your `t1` never finishes, your main thread waits for it indefinitely.

***Edit:***

To run two threads indefinitely and concurrency, first create the threads, and *then* wait for both:

```
int main() {
    thread t1(Loop);
    thread t2(SecondLoop);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: @Purixi, it's unclear what you are attempting to achieve. Do you want to brake one thread from another one? You may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768814/run-and-break-an-infinite-loop-using-two-threads) usefl

Comment: I edited the question to show you what I need to do.

Answer (score 2):

To run `Loop` and `SecondLoop` concurrency, you have to do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void Loop() {
    while(true) {
        //(do something)
    }
}

void SecondLoop() {
    while(true) {
        //(do something)
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(Loop);
    std::thread t2(SecondLoop);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

as `join` block current thread to wait the other thread finishes.

Answer (score 1):

.join() waits for the thread to end (so in this case if you break out of the while loops and exit the thread function)

Answer (score 0):

using while(true) is linked to the tread running , you should look for a way to exit that loop, use some sort of loop control

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment and what @Nidhoegger answered I suggest:

```
int main() {
    thread t1(Loop);
    thread t2(SecondLoop);
    // Your 2 threads will run now in paralel
    // ... <- So some other things with your application
    // Now you want to close the app, perhaps all work is done or the user asked it to quit
    // Notify threads to stop
    t1running = false;
    t2running = false;
    // Wait for all threads to stop
    t1.join();
    t2.join(); 
    // Exit program
    return false;
```

}