# How to thread a chain of while(true) inside classes to join without getting stuck? C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, join

Each Chain1, Chain2, Chain3, all the same class structure only really difference is with the threaded Dofunction inside, so essentially they are the same class except for that one DoFunction. Isn't this doing something like the solution to [How do I use while true in threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33431445/how-do-i-use-while-true-in-threads)
The following is a general idea of what I am trying to accomplish. The second thread hangs up when I try to join.

```
main()
{
   Chain1 generator;
   Chain2 preprocessor;
   Chain3 processor;

   // to communicate to the parent for data transfer
   processsor.makeChild(&generator);
   processor.makeChild(&preprocessor);

   // initialize the threads
   generator.init();
   preprocessor.init();
   processor.init();

   // join the threads
   generator.start();
   preprocessor.start(); // issue here hangs up here trying to join
   processor.start();
}

class Chain1 //or Chain2 or Chain3...
{
     init()
     {
         // stored as a class member
         chain_thread = std::thread(&Chain1::Dofunction, this); // or std::thread(&Chain::Chain2::Dofunction, this); // or std::thread(&Chain::Chain3::Dofunction, this);
     }
     start()
     {
        chain_thread.join();   
     }
     Dofunction()
     {
         while(true)
         {
             //...  different for each Chain1, Chain2, Chain3
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: "Different" how? I don't really understand the question. Just write the code - what is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Based on the names of the variables involved I guess you try to create a pipeline with three steps - generation, pre-processing and processing - where the generator continuously creates new values that should be passed through the pipeline, correct?

Comment: what is the question? What is the problem? Do this threads communicate somehow?

Comment: // join the threads
   generator.start();
   preprocessor.start(); // issue here hangs up here trying to join
   processor.start();

Comment: The second thread I try to join hangs up. Aren't I doing something similar as the solution in the link?

Comment: Yup, I am creating a pipleline. The issue I am having is with joining the threads together after initializing them.

Comment: What's `Chain1`, `Chain2` and `Chain3`, and how, if at all, are they related to `Chain`? Show a [mcve]

Comment: C++ threads can be connected by streams, and linux pipeline uses these for process to process.  I created (a few year ago) a 'pipeline' class to support thread to thread communications within a single ubuntu process.  I modeled my "Class Filter" to achieve a type of data flow and throttling-feedback  (to the threads) to model the linux pipeline.  I think contexts-witch times are something to learn about _before_ spending too much time on this style.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you are missunderstanding the purpose of [`std::thread::join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join). The function is not for starting the threads. The function blocks the caller (so basically your main-thread) until the thread (chain-thread) has finished the execution.

So, what's basically happening is:
1. You create the threads in the `chainX::init()` function. The threads start running the infinite loop from that point.
2. You `join` the threads in your main function, which basically means that you are waiting for the threads to finish their execution (which they don't because they are in a endless loop? you don't show what's happening inside the `Dofunction`)

You need a break condition in you while loop. As I do not know what should stop your threads, the following is just pseudocode:

```
Dofunction()
     {
         while(true)
         {
             //...  different for each Chain1, Chain2, Chain3
             if(work_done == true) break;
         }
     }
```

The `work_done` could be anything from checking if the work queue is empty or a signal from the main thread indicating that the the work should be stopped.